# Best way to bind shell output to a struct in Go?

Tags: bash, go, awk

I have some chips running on some hardware and I want to bind the output of a shell command to a struct to do reporting/logging on.

```
Num item1: 2
INDEX LOAD MODEL_LOAD INST MEM  SHARE_MEM P2P_MEM DEVICE         NAMESPACE
1     2    3          4    50    600         700       1     1
1a     2b    3c          4c    5d    6e         7f       2     2
Num item2: 2
INDEX LOAD MODEL_LOAD INST MEM  SHARE_MEM P2P_MEM DEVICE         NAMESPACE
2a     2b    2c          3    0    0         0       1     1
1     0    0          0    0    0         0       2     2
**************************************************
```

### Attempt

```
cat out.txt | grep -i "Num $1" -A 3 | grep -i nvme | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1-7
```

This actually isn't too bad, I can pass in an arg like `decoders` or `encoders` and get the load metrics for each chip. However, I'm curious now the best way to bind this to a struct in Go.

Currently, what I can do is code up a custom deserializer from something like:

```golang
func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "metrics.sh", "encoders").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

But I feel like there has to be a better way, like outputting as JSON and binding to a struct or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert your input file to CSV, because it suits the original tabular data and also because the Go language have a CSV encoder/decoder in its standard library:

```bash
awk -v OFS=',' '
    $1 == "Num" {
        count = $3
        type = $2

        getline
        if ( !header++ ) {
            $(NF+1) = "ID"
            print
        }
        for ( id = 1; id <= count; id++ ) {
            getline
            $(NF+1) = type id
            print
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

<sup>**Warning:** the code doesn't CSV-escape the fields</sup>

```
INDEX,LOAD,MODEL_LOAD,INST,MEM,SHARE_MEM,P2P_MEM,DEVICE,NAMESPACE,ID
1,2,3,4,50,600,700,/dev/nvme0,/dev/nvme0n1,decoders:1
1a,2b,3c,4c,5d,6e,7f,/dev/nvme1,/dev/nvme1n1,decoders:2
2a,2b,2c,3,0,0,0,/dev/nvme0,/dev/nvme0n1,encoders:1
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,/dev/nvme1,/dev/nvme1n1,encoders:2
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,/dev/nvme0,/dev/nvme0n1,scalers:1
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,/dev/nvme1,/dev/nvme1n1,scalers:2
```

**N.B.** Writing a parser in Go for your input format shouldn't be that difficult

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, gives me something to think about. Cheers!

Comment: Brushing up on some AWK. What is header in this case? Is that a reserved keyword in AWK?

Comment: @user38643 `header` is just a variable that I use for knowing if I already printed the CSV header

Comment: ah I see now, it is 0 by default and you increment to 1 which will then no-op on future iterations. I'm dissecting each line.

Comment: Ok, after reading the script, it all makes sense. This is very clean, thanks again

Comment: Last question I had. If I don't want to append the ID column, the output format of CSV is malformed. I've removed the contents inside the first if and omitted the NF+1 in the for loop. Why would that be invalid?

Comment: @user38643 if a field isn't modified then `awk` doesn't reprocess the input line; you can force the reprocessing with `$1 = $1`

Answer (score 2):

How about starting directly with the text you care about in Go? You'll have far more control in Go than you'll ever have with shell utilities.

This is a little state machine that looks for the leading text, "Num", to indicate the beginning of a new Item. The next line is the header, which is skipped, and following lines are converted to a Row, which are added to that Item.  At the boundary between items and at the end of the input text/file, the last Item is added to the set of all Items.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var txt = `
Num item1: 2
INDEX LOAD MODEL_LOAD INST MEM  SHARE_MEM P2P_MEM DEVICE         NAMESPACE
1     2    3          4    50    600         700       1     1
1a     2b    3c          4c    5d    6e         7f       2     2
Num item2: 2
INDEX LOAD MODEL_LOAD INST MEM  SHARE_MEM P2P_MEM DEVICE         NAMESPACE
2a     2b    2c          3    0    0         0       1     1
1     0    0          0    0    0         0       2     2
Num item3: 1
INDEX LOAD MODEL_LOAD INST MEM  SHARE_MEM P2P_MEM DEVICE         NAMESPACE
i     iib    iic          iii    zero    zero         zero       i     i
**************************************************
`

var columns = regexp.MustCompile(`\s+`)

type Row struct {
    Index,
    Load,
    Model_Load,
    Inst_Mem,
    Share_Mem,
    P2p_Mem,
    Device,
    Namespace string
}

type Item []Row

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(txt)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)

    items := make([]Item, 0)

    var item Item
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        line = strings.TrimSpace(line)

        if len(line) == 0 ||
            strings.HasPrefix(line, "***") {
            continue
        }

        // find beginning of an "item": if any previous item, save it and
        // reset item to append future rows; skip header line; continue
        if strings.HasPrefix(line, "Num item") {
            if len(item) > 0 {
                items = append(items, item)
                item = make(Item, 0)
            }
            scanner.Scan() // skip header
            continue
        }

        cols := columns.Split(line, -1)
        row := Row{cols[0], cols[1], cols[2], cols[3], cols[4], cols[5], cols[6], cols[7]}
        item = append(item, row)
    }

    // deal with last/trailing item
    if len(item) > 0 {
        items = append(items, item)
    }

    for i, item := range items {
        fmt.Printf("Item %d\n", i+1)
        for _, row := range item {
            fmt.Println(row)
        }
    }
}
```

That prints the following:

```
Item 1
{1 2 3 4 50 600 700 1}
{1a 2b 3c 4c 5d 6e 7f 2}
Item 2
{2a 2b 2c 3 0 0 0 1}
{1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2}
Item 3
{i iib iic iii zero zero zero i}
```

I don't know of a better way to create the struct, but it is direct, and fairly clean.

Comment: OP should parse the input file in GO like here, but I don't like fixing the number and the names of the columns in the code when it is possible to set it dynamically: read until finding a `Num` (from which you get the number of lines of data), then read the header, then read the specified number of lines of data; then search for a `Num`, etc... +1

Comment: @Fravadona, yes, this could benefit from a little state machine if OP needs to distinguish between sets (and they probably do). I might get around to implementing and editing... but, "fixing the number and the names of the columns"... I don't get your meaning. Please clarify :)

Comment: You're defining a fixed number of columns and names with `type Row struct { Index, Load, ...}` while you'll be reading a line with `INDEX LOAD ...`, so if you keep this "header" in the array `header` then you could do something like this: `var row map[string]string; row[header[0]] := cols[0]; ...`

Comment: @Fravadona Hmm, I'm still not quite following your train of thought. OP asked for the data to be put in a struct; I don't see how a map gets them what they want. I'd like to see your solution.

Comment: IDK if OP cares about a `struct`; what I proposed is a way to build something equivalent to the JSON `[ {"INDEX": "1", "LOAD": "2", ...}, {"INDEX": "1a", "LOAD": "2b", ...}, ... ]`